# Перевести строки из текстового файла в QML TableView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator, qml

Есть содержимое текстового файла:

```
user_id_1; user_name_1; phone_number_1;
user_id_2; user_name_2; phone_number_2;
```

Нужно перевести это все в QML TableView под столбцами userid, username, phonenumber(хочу понять логику работы). Собственно сам интерфейс нарисован:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Work application")

    Connections {
        target: app
        onSendToQML: {
            pathtxt.text = path
        }
    }

    TableView {
        sortIndicatorOrder: 0
        anchors.bottomMargin: 55
        anchors.fill: parent

            TableViewColumn {
                role: "user_id"    // Эти роли совпадают с названиями ролей в C++ модели
                title: "User ID"
            }

            TableViewColumn {
                role: "username"    // Эти роли совпадают с названиями ролей в C++ модели
                title: "Username"
            }

            TableViewColumn {
                role: "phone_number"    // Эти роли совпадают с названиями ролей в C++ модели
                title: "Phone number"
            }
            // Устанавливаем модель в TableView
            model: myModel

            Button {
                x: 533
                y: 441
                text: "Задать путь!"
                onClicked: app.receiveFromQml()
            }

            TextInput {
                x: 250
                y: 441
                width: 224
                height: 23
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                font.family: "Arial"
                cursorVisible: true
            }

            Text {
                id: pathtxt
                x: 0
                y: 441
                width: 223
                height: 23
                text: "Введите путь до файла с расширением .txt: "
                textFormat: Text.AutoText
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
            }

        }
}
```

И реализован участок кода для извлечения строк из файла:

```
void app::receiveFromQml(QString path)
{
    QFile file1(path);
    if(file1.exists())
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file1);
        while (!stream.atEnd())
        {
            QString line = stream.readLine();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно создать под это дело модель на стороне С++, а потом уже передать её параметру `model` вашего `TableView`. Как это делать написано тут - [тыц](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html)

Приведу пример из вышеприведенного источника, имеем ListView модель:

```
ListView {
    width: 100; height: 100
    model: myModel
    delegate: Rectangle {
        height: 25
        width: 100
        Text { text: modelData }
    }
}
```

На стороне С++, чтобы привязать QStringList в виде модели делаем следующее:

```
QStringList dataList;
dataList.append("Item 1");
dataList.append("Item 2");
dataList.append("Item 3");
dataList.append("Item 4");

QQuickView view;
QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(dataList));
```

Пример на русском с хабра:
[тыц](https://habr.com/ru/post/302428/)

Comment: У вас имеется такой же мануал(возможно с видео), но на русском? Спасибо.

Comment: @csharperbegin обновил